# How are the formulae of isochoric processes used in adiabatic processes?

Tags: thermodynamics

We have the formula for an isochoric process:

$c_V = \frac{\mathrm{d}E}{\mathrm{d}T}$ at constant volume.

$c_V=$ molar heat capacity at constant volume.

But it's given for adiabatic changes,
$$\delta E=c_V\cdot \Delta T=W$$

How is this an equation for an adiabatic process when it's derived from equations of an isochoric process?

Is an adiabatic process also isochoric?

Where am I going wrong?

Comment: Convenient reference for text/formula formatting:
 [Notation basics](https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/help/notation)  /  [Formatting of math/chem expressions](https://chemistry.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/86/how-can-i-format-math-chemistry-expressions-here)  /  
[upright vs italic](https://chemistry.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/443/which-symbols-are-written-in-roman-upright-font-and-which-are-italicized)  // [For more:  Math SE MathJax tutorial](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference).  // Not to be applied in CH SE titles.

Comment: The heat capacity and internal energy of an ideal gas is independent of volume.  For cases where the gas is non-ideal, your equation for adiabatic changes is incorrect.